# Error: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_Conv2D1: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow

```
async function train() {
    
    var labels = [0] // 0 = L 
    var tensorLabels = tf.oneHot(tf.tensor1d(labels, 'int32'), 3);

    var buffer = fs.readFileSync("./train/L/L.png")
    var tensorFeature = tf.node.decodeImage(buffer)

    var tensorFeatures = tf.stack([tensorFeature])
    
    const model = tf.sequential();
    model.add(tf.layers.conv2d({
      inputShape: [1, 132, 180, 3], // numberOfChannels = 3 for colorful images and one otherwise
      filters: 32,
      kernelSize: 3,
      activation: 'relu',
    }));
    model.add(tf.layers.flatten()),
    model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 3, activation: 'softmax'}));

    model.compile({loss: 'meanSquaredError', optimizer: 'sgd'})
    model.fit(tensorFeatures, tensorLabels)
}
```

I am trying to train a tensorflow model with the letter "L" (132x180), and I'm pretty new to tf. I am hoping I can get some help with training using images.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by changing the inputShape:

```
 inputShape: [180, 132, 3],
```